# Rails Cocoon read only fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using Cocoon for nested forms. For `task` records **that are already created**, I want `description` to be read_only.

projects/_form::

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :description
  %h3 Tasks
  #tasks
    = f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task|
      = render 'task_fields', f: task
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks
  = f.submit
```

And _task_fields :

```
.nested-fields
  - if @task.description?
    = f.text_field :description, disabled: true
  - else
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :done, as: :boolean
  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

Currently the validation in `_task_fields` is not working: `undefined method <description> for nil:NilClass` in the line with `if` statement. How can I write the `IF statement` correctly?

Comment: What is the problem that you are having currently?

Comment: `disabled: true` should work with `Cocoon`, I see `else` section (`= f.input :description`) does not have `disabled: true`

Comment: The idea is to have the description `read_only` for records that have been saved previously, and editable when rendering a 'new task'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For task records that are already created, I want description to be
>   read_only.

You are doing it wrong. You should be able do the check by using [`new_record?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) like so

```
.nested-fields
  - unless f.object.new_record?
    = f.text_field :description, disabled: true
  - else
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :done, as: :boolean
  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

Also, by using `disabled: true`, the value of description won't be submitted and cannot be passed through `params`. If you want to have the description value in the `params`, use `readonly: true` instead.

```
.nested-fields
  - unless f.object.new_record?
    = f.text_field :description, readonly: true
  - else
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :done, as: :boolean
  = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```